# how to send Id using httppost Securely

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

look at follwing Sample Codes
 I easily can change id and then edit another movie
how can I have a secure form?

```html
<form action="/movies/Edit/4" method="post">
   <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="UxY6bkQyJCXO3Kn5AXg-6TXxOj6yVBi9tghHaQ5Lq_qwKvcojNXEEfcbn-FGh_0vuw4tS_BRk7QQQHlJp8AP4_X4orVNoQnp2cd8kXhykS01" />  <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
      <legend>Movie</legend>

      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="4" />

      <div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="Title">Title</label>
         <div class="controls">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="GhostBusters" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid help-inline" data-valmsg-for="Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="ReleaseDate">Release Date</label>
         <div class="controls">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Release Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Release Date field is required." id="ReleaseDate" name="ReleaseDate" type="date" value="1/1/1984" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid help-inline" data-valmsg-for="ReleaseDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="Genre">Genre</label>
         <div class="controls">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="Genre" name="Genre" type="text" value="Comedy" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid help-inline" data-valmsg-for="Genre" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="Price">Price</label>
         <div class="controls">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Price must be a number." data-val-required="The Price field is required." id="Price" name="Price" type="text" value="7.99" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid help-inline" data-valmsg-for="Price" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-actions no-color">
         <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn" />
      </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you care if someone change the ID? If the user has the right to change the movie with that ID everything is fine. If the the user is **not** allowed to change the movie with that ID then check that in the post method and throw an error

Comment: BTW Did you see the ID value is doubled? The form action includes the ID and the hidden field too

Comment: Simply put, given the user has the right to edit a given movie, if they want to "hack" the form and pass some data fetched from some other movie, let them. They might consider that a feature, e.g. copy from one to the other.

Comment: If a user should not change the ID in a form, just don't give her the means to do so. You could just not display the field or make it not editable. I think it is a good idea to think about security. Much of it can be achieved by not providing functionality that is not needed.

Comment: @DanielSchmid Well, the ID has to be present in some way. How will you know which ID these changes refer to? And everything in the html can be edited by the browser/user

Answer (score 0):

You can include the request path into the AntiForgery Token.

Declare a class that implements `IAntiforgeryAdditionalDataProvider` like this

```
public class AntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider : IAntiforgeryAdditionalDataProvider
{
    public string GetAdditionalData( HttpContext context )
    {
        return context.Request.Path.Value;
    }

    public bool ValidateAdditionalData( HttpContext context, string additionalData )
    {
        return context.Request.Path.Value == additionalData;
    }
}
```

and register that class `Startup`

```
public class Startup
{
    ...

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
    {
        // add this at first!
        services.TryAddSingleton<IAntiforgeryAdditionalDataProvider, AntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    ...
}
```

Now every `AntiForgeryToken` is build and validated with the path `/movies/Edit/4`